# Proving $ 2\arcsin\left(\sinh(x)\right) + \arccos\left( 2 - \cosh(2x) \right) = 0 $

Tags: trigonometry

> $$ 2\arcsin\big( \sinh(x) \big) + \arccos\big( 2 - \cosh(2x) \big) = 0 $$

If this is true, then for what values of $x$?  (Clearly, the $\arcsin(\cdot)$ and $\arccos(\cdot)$ are not valid for *every* real argument.)

Comment: as i fiddle with this, it appears to me that below is true for all real $x$ such that $-\operatorname{arcsinh}(1) \le x \le \operatorname{arcsinh}(1)$ :

$$ 2\arcsin\left( \sinh(x) \right) = \operatorname{sgn}(x) \arccos\left( 2 - \cosh(2x) \right) $$

it's odd that we need the $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ since the left-hand side seems pretty continuous (and it is odd-symmetry).  but the right-hand side would be even-symmetry without the $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does this identity come from?

Comment: @anon, i had done a quick calculation of the frequency response of a 1-pole low-pass digital filter with z-transform: $$ H(z) = \frac{1-p}{z-p} $$ and this is evaluated on the unit circle $z=e^{i \omega}$ and i solve for the $\omega$ that is the *"half-power frequency"*: $|H(e^{i \omega_0})|^2 = \tfrac12$.  i had also done this simple problem 4 decades ago as an electrical engineering student and came up with a different answer.  both answers are correct and this identity came from equating the two and simplifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall a couple double-angle formulas valid for all $x$:

$$ \cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x), \\ \cosh(2x)=1+2\sinh^2(x). \tag{1}$$

Apply $u\mapsto 2-u$ to the latter so we may write

$$ 1-2\sinh^2(x)=2-\cosh(2x). \tag{2}$$

Use the substitution $\sinh(x)=\sin(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is in $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, the range of $\arcsin$. This way the left side of $(2)$ is just $\cos(2\theta)$, so we may write this as

$$ \cos(2\theta)=2-\cosh(2x). \tag{3}$$

Split into two cases: either $2\theta$ is in $[0,\pi]$, the range of $\arccos$, or it's in $[-\pi,0]$.

In the first case, we can apply $\arccos$ to both sides of $(3)$ to obtain

$$ 2\theta=\arccos(2-\cosh(2x)) \tag{4a}$$

In the second case, we have $2\theta=-\arccos(\cos(2\theta))$, so from $(3)$ we get

$$ 2\theta=-\arccos(2-\cosh(2x)). \tag{4b}$$

The conditions on $\theta$ can be turned into conditions on $x$:

$$ \begin{array}{rrrrr} 0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2} & \iff & 0\le \sin\theta\le 1 & \iff & 0\le x\le\sinh^{-1}(1) \\ -\frac{\pi}{2}\le\theta\le0 & \iff & -1\le\sin\theta\le0 & \iff & -\sinh^{-1}(1)\le x\le0 \end{array} \tag{5}$$

Finally, replace $\theta$ with $\arcsin(\sinh(x))$. In conclusion,

$$ \arcsin(\sinh(x))=\mathrm{sgn}(x)\arccos(2-\cosh(2x)) $$ for all $-\sinh^{-1}(1)\le x\le \sinh^{-1}(1).~$ (Note $\sinh^{-1}(1)=\ln(1+\sqrt{2})\approx 0.88$.)

Comment: it's the use of the double-angle formula (for $\cos(\omega)$) that makes the connection.  in my recent solving of the one-pole digital filter problem, i had made use of it and 4 decades ago when i did this, i had **not** made use of the double-angle formula and came up with a result that, while correct, looked quite different than the result i had yesterday.  thank you [anon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11763/anon) for nailing this.  i will probably write this up as a question and answer at the DSP SE, which is where i hang most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
L(x) = 2\arcsin(\sinh(x)) \\
R(x) = -\arccos(2-2\cosh(x))
$$
I'll show that these functions are equal for $x \ge 0$ when $|\sinh(x)| \le 1$.

Step 1: check that $L(0) = R(0)$. Yes.

Step 2: Check that $L'(x) = R'(x)$ for all $x$.

Start from the following: for $0 \le u \le 1$, we have

$$
\sqrt{4u^2 - 4u^4} = 2u \sqrt{1-u^2},
$$
because $u > 0$, so we don't need the absolute value sign on the right (although including it would probably deal with the case where $x < 0$ later, but I leave that to OP).

Then
\begin{align}
\sqrt{1 - (1 - 4u^2 + 4u^4)} &= 2u \sqrt{1-u^2} \\
\sqrt{1 - (1 - 2u^2)^2} &= 2u \sqrt{1-u^2}. 
\end{align}
If we replace $u$ with $\sinh(x)$, we get
\begin{align}
\sqrt{1 - (1 - 2\sinh^2(x))^2} &= 2\sinh(x) \sqrt{1-\sinh^2(x)}\\
\sqrt{1 - (2 - \cosh^2 (x) - \sinh^2(x))^2} &= 2\sinh(x) \sqrt{1-\sinh^2(x)}\\
\cosh(x)\sqrt{1 - (2 - \cosh^2 (x) - \sinh^2(x))^2} &= 2\cosh(x)\sinh(x) \sqrt{1-\sinh^2(x)}\\
\cosh(x)\sqrt{1 - (2 - \cosh^2 (x) - \sinh^2(x))^2} &= \sinh(2x) \sqrt{1-\sinh^2(x)}\\
2\cosh(x)\sqrt{1 - (2 - \cosh^2 (x) - \sinh^2(x))^2} &= 2\sinh(2x) \sqrt{1-\sinh^2(x)}\\
\frac{2\cosh(x)}{\sqrt{1-\sinh^2(x)}} &= \frac{2\sinh(2x)}{\sqrt{1 - (2 - \cosh^2 (x) - \sinh^2(x))^2}}\\
\frac{2\cosh(x)}{\sqrt{1-\sinh^2(x)}} &= \frac{2\sinh(2x)}{\sqrt{1 - (2 - \cosh(2x))^2}}\\
\end{align}

The left hand side of this is just $L'(x)$; the right hand side is $R'(x)$. Because they're equal, and $L(0) = R(0)$, we have that $L(x) = R(x)$ within the specified domain (by the FTC, if you want to get fancy).

In short: the OP's statement, with a sign-fix, is correct for positive $x$; a similar proof, without the sign-change, presumably demonstrates the original claim for negative $x$. The whole thing is an exercise in algebra and the FTC.

Comment: if, by *"FTC"*, you mean the *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus*, that seems curious to me because this only about trig and hyperbolic trig identities.  there are no derivatives nor integrals nor anti-derivatives.  i dunno what the FTC has to do with it.

Comment: and i'm correcting my previous misconception that the FTC was.   i understand the proof now.

Comment: One way to prove two differentiable functions are equal is to show they agree at one point, and that they have the same derivative. The proof that this suffices to show equality is usually via the FTC, although other tools can work, too. (I think that there might be one involving the mean value theorem, for instance, but I'm by no means certain.) When in step 2 I wrote $L'$ and $R'$, those were derivatives.

Comment: i understand and correct my earlier misstatement about the role of the FTC in this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks wrong to Desmos:
[image]

So...I guess that it's probably almost never true (except perhaps for $x = 0$).

Details:
Let's look at $x = \frac{1}{2}$.

Now here's a matlab program to test that out:

```
function silly()
x = 0.5
a = sinh(x)
b = asin(a)
c = 2 * b

'part 2'
d = cosh(1)
f = 2 - d
g = acos(f)

'sum'
c + g
```

and the results of executing it:

```
>> silly
x =
    0.5000
a =
    0.5211
b =
    0.5481
c =
    1.0963
ans =
   'part 2'
d =
    1.5431
f =
    0.4569
g =
    1.0963
ans =
    'sum'
ans =
    2.1925
```

If $2.1925$ looks like zero to within roundoff error, then *you* are correct; if not, then Desmos and I are correct. It's telling that the two parts look identical, so that their *difference* at $x = 0.5$ would be zero, while their sum is nonzero.

(To be fair, I should say that I was half-correct --- it's almost never true for positive $x$; it appears to be identically true for negative $x$.)

Comment: in MATLAB i do this: $$ $$>> x = linspace(-1, 0, 1025);
$$ $$>> y1 = 2*asin(sinh(x));
$$ $$>> y2 = acos(2 - cosh(2*x));
$$ $$>> plot(x,y1+y2)
$$ $$ and i get virtually zero (for all 1025 values of x from -1 to 0).

Comment: i got some MATLAB complaint about ignoring imaginary values.  so i changed it to $$ $$ >> x = linspace(-0.87, 0, 1025);

Comment: sorry, John, i just think you're wrong.

Comment: See my additions to my answer. The equality is definitely false for $x = 0.5$.

Comment: that is true, John.  my OP was both about proving the identity and identifying what values of $x$ that the identity holds. but to be fair, the original answer (or guess): *"... that it's probably almost never true (except perhaps for x=0)"* is simply wrong.  that answer is not even half-correct.

Comment: Ah, well. So I identified a falsehood in your conjecture (the "identity" was not, in fact, an identity), corrected it, and proved the corrected version, even after you claimed my original work was wrong (which it wasn't; only my guess was). No good deed goes unpunished.

Comment: i didn't downvote your good deed.

Answer (score 0):

If we use the Taylor series, $\arcsin(\sinh(x))\approx x+\frac {x^3}3+\frac {x^5}6$ and $\arccos(2-2-\cosh(2x))\approx |2x+\frac {2x^3}3+\frac {x^5}3|$ so for $x \gt 0$ the dominant term is $4x$.  For $x \lt 0$ the first through fifth order terms cancel.

Comment: for all $x$ such that $-0.87 \le x \le 0$, i get less than $10^{-13}$ in magnitude.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson:  yes, the fifth order terms cancel as well.  I suspect that the difference is that the arccosine is defined to give a positive result while the first term has the same sign as $x$.  For $x \gt 0$ both terms are positive.

Comment: well, i was deriving frequency response of a simple first order filter.  then i looked at notes i had from 40 years ago and i had a totally different result.
looks like they're both valid results.

Comment: i'm gonna investigate and will report my result when i know what the heck i did differently between now and when i was an EE student ca. 1978.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a typo; changing the $+$ to $-$ makes

$$2\arcsin\big( \sinh(x) \big) \color{red}{-} \arccos\big( 2 - \cosh(2x) \big) = 0$$  true for all $x \geq 0$.

Composing Taylor series built at $x=0$ and assuming $x >0$, we have
$$2\arcsin\big( \sinh(x) \big)=2 x+\frac{2 x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{3}+\frac{79 x^7}{315}+\frac{493
   x^9}{2268}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$
$$\arccos\big( 2 - \cosh(2x) \big)=2 x+\frac{2 x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{3}+\frac{79 x^7}{315}+\frac{493
   x^9}{2268}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$

Comment: not for $-\operatorname{arcsinh}(1) \le x \le 0$.  when $x$ is in that range, it's a $+$ sign.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson. You are correct ! I shall fix it.

Comment: so you're saying it works also for $0 \le x \le \operatorname{arcsinh}(1)$?

Comment: Claude, while i appreciate seeing the first five terms of the Taylor series (and that they are identical between the two expressions), this is not yet the proof that i seek.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson. I never said that it was a proof ! By the way, there are very interesting features for $x <0$.

Comment: i know that you didn't call it a proof.  and i didn't mean to imply that.

but with these first 5 terms identical, i strongly suspect the rest to be identical.

Comment: @robertbristow. Is the problem $+$ or $-$ ?

Comment: for $x<0$, i think that the problem is stated accurately in my question.  it's funny but to cover it for + or - $x$, there needs to be a $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ (which is discontinuous about $x=0$) in there.  it looks continuous, with continuous derivatives on one side but discontinuous on the other.